In Rom 5:15 is Christ the grace of God or the means of bestowing grace?
My question about Rom 5:15 is about the identity of what Paul calls a man's Grace. In a previous post it was pointed out that God's grace and Christ's grace refer to the same thing. I think there are several problems with that interpretation.
First, grace does not come from the humanity of Christ but from God. God is the source of grace and bestows it on humanity. God gives grace and humanity receives it.
Second, how to interpret the genitives that Paul uses. It is grace that is bestowed by a man (genitive), namely Jesus Christ (genitive).
ἡ δωρεὰ ἐν χάριτι τῇ τοῦ ἑνὸς ἀνθρώπου Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ
The context contrasts two men, Adam who brings sin and condemnation vs Christ, the other man, who brings righteousness and justification.
It seems to me that χάριτι is being defined, not as something Christ offers as man, but what Christ is as man. In other words, grace is the New Man that God has given us to counteract what the first man did. So we would have to translate: The grace that is a man, that is Christ.
Could someone tell me if my conclusion is possible?

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Up-voted +1 for a good question, well thought out and competently researched.

This question is similar to: Grace of God vs the Grace of the One Man Jesus Christ (Rom 5:15). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


But the free gift is not like the trespass. For if the many died
through the one man’s trespass, much more surely have the grace of God
and the gift in the grace of the one man, Jesus Christ, abounded for
the many. (NABRE)

As much as it goes against the grain, the plain sense of the text is that "one man" provided grace to the many. One may certainly interpret this to mean that God was providing grace through this man. Indeed Paul himself says as much in 2 Corinthians 5:19:

In Christ God was reconciling the world to himself, not counting their
trespasses against them, and entrusting the message of reconciliation
to us.

Conclusion: from the standpoint of traditional Christian soteriology the OP is quite right to suggest that grace does not come from Jesus' humanity but from his divinity. However, traditional christology tells us that the divine and human natures of Christ are undivided, so perhaps the OP is making an unnecessary distinction. (I will leave the question about genitives to those with expertise in Greek.)

Is grace, in this context, a simple attitude of God or an event? Note that grace provides something: righteousness. If that righteousness is found in the Man Jesus, it follows that what grace provides is what pertains to that man's humanity. That man is constituted in the grace of God. My proposition is that “the grace of a man” is equivalent to what John 3:16 states “God has given us his Son.” The incarnation is grace made man.

We are talking about the original Adam and the new Adam here so this makes sense, but there are going to be various interpretations. (You may find that some members of the community will object to your question as "opinion-based").

+1. This is a good answer.  Further, if Jesus was not 100% human (as well as 100% divine) He could not have died on the cross and then resurrected Himself, etc.  Thus, Jesus human nature were essential to providing grace, just as His divine nature (undivided) divine nature were.

It is true that we cannot divide his divinity from his humanity, nor can we confuse them. God resurrects Christ's flesh as a reward for his obedience. Christ was justified by his resurrection (Rom 4:25).  The humanity of Christ is the grace granted to man; that humanity receives vicariously our curse, our death, our justification and is restored to him the lordship of the new creation. Christ is the name of the exalted Man (Acts 2:36), who receives the lordship lost by Adam (Heb 2). He is the New Man.
